# Power BI - How to get the row count of a column at the bottom?

Tags: powerbi, rowcount

The data I am working with have a column called 'Historical Date'that has blank fields too. I am trying to determine how can I show the total number of dates (rows in historical date column) in that column at the bottom?
Do I need to create a specific DAX measure?

Comment: Are you looking to create a table visualization, with date in the rows and the number of dates at the bottom? It would be great if you can make the ask a little clearer, maybe with a sample output

Comment: Yes, I have a date column i.e., 'Historical Date' in a table visualization. I want to look at the total number of dates at the bottom.

Comment: for example, Historical Date - 05/31/2019, 09/11/2019, blank, 07/04/2019, blank,-----and so on. In this case, total number of dates is 3. This is what I want to look at the bottom of the column.

Answer (score -2):

You can simply use Count(Date), but this will be shown as a different column, not at the bottom of the column. I don't think there is any way to show them in the same table. However, there are workarounds to make it look the way you are expecting. I am going to list one possible way to do this:

- Create a table visualization with all the desired fields along with
  the historical date field (Let's call this Table1)
- Remove the total calculation from Table1
- Create another table visualization which has just the total count, calculated as count(Date). Let's call this Table2
- Move Table2 below Table1 to make it look like they are the
  same table

Hope this helps.